# num_rows with prepared statement returns 0 rows when equivalent normal query returns more

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having some problems with prepared statements in Mysqli and I’m not sure why.

I have a database which currently has 3 rows, which I want to select using a `SELECT WHERE` query.  The query which works in PhpMyAdmin is:

```
SELECT `totalhits`, `totalmisses`, `date` 
FROM `performance` 
WHERE `domain` = 'test' AND `profileid` = 1 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

This shows all three rows (all have `domain = test` and `profileid=1`.)

If I run this with a normal query in Mysqli and hard-coded variables, I get the same result:

```
$query = $conn->query(“SELECT `totalhits`, `totalmisses`, `date` FROM `performance` WHERE `domain` = 'test' AND `profileid` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC”);
echo $query->num_rows; //outputs 3
```

If I try and run it as a parameter query (as I will be using user entered data), I get 0 rows returned:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `totalhits`, `totalmisses`, `date` FROM `performance` WHERE `domain` = ? AND `profileid` = ? ORDER BY `date` DESC");
$domain = 'test';
$profileid = 1;
$stmt->bind_param('si', $domain,$profileid);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->num_rows; //outputs 0
```

No Mysqli errors are generated by any of these lines (using print_r on the object at each point to check).  I also added a `$stmt->store_result()` line after the execute line but still had the same result (should I be doing this anyway?).

Comment: `num_rows` is a property, not a method.

Comment: @u_mulder again quite right (sorry I've been looking at this so long I'm not spotting the obvious). With that corrected I'm still getting the original result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [`mysqli_stmt::num_rows`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) misses some detailed information about using `num_rows` with prepared statements. The description is rather ambiguous in that it refers only to the need to store the result when using the procedural style, **but** the [object-oriented example](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php#example-1885) makes it clear that you need to call the `store_result()` method before accessing the `num_rows` property. This means your code should be something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `totalhits`, `totalmisses`, `date` FROM `performance` WHERE `domain` = ? AND `profileid` = ? ORDER BY `date` DESC");
$domain = 'test';
$profileid = 1;
$stmt->bind_param('si', $domain,$profileid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows; //should now output 3
```

Comment: I finally realised this about 30 seconds before you posted your answer - thanks so much for your help!  I will accept when I can in a few minutes

Comment: @Rory I'm glad I was able to help you with your question. These kind of questions keep me busy (in a positive way). It is sad to see that the documentation is sometimes unclear.